# Android.Webkit.WebView not load url in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, android-intent, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

`Android.Webkit.WebView` not load url

I Created a method in main activity class this method have a WebView but not load url

```
public void LaunchBrowserView(string authorizationServerUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                var web_view = new Android.Webkit.WebView(this);

                web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                web_view.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
                //web_view.Settings.= true;
                //web_view.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;
                web_view.SetWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
                web_view.Settings.LoadsImagesAutomatically = true;
                web_view.LoadUrl(authorizationServerUrl);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

```
class MyBrowser : WebViewClient
    {
        override public bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
        {
            view.LoadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }

        public override void OnReceivedSslError(Android.Webkit.WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error)
        {
            base.OnReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need a static variable exactly?

Comment: Hello @FreakyAli i edited my question please see.

Comment: This seems to look like a service. So are you creating this service in your MainActivity itself? Also, why do you need your WebView in the service anyway? Also don't you think doing what you are doing would create a memory leak since your activity would never be disposed?

Comment: i am loading a web url

Comment: loading a URL in the service? why do you need that I mean I am confused!

Comment: this activity calling a button click event

Comment: My login part on web and return a token

Comment: Do you mean the webview does not show the website?

Comment: Yes @WendyZang Web view not load url

Comment: @Deepakyogi What is the url? Do you want to do more operation for the url before your load?

Comment: @Deepakyogi I test the code you provided, maybe you invoke in the wrong way. I use `https://www.google.com` as authorizationServerUrl, if you do not have special requirement for the url, I will post the code on my own.

Comment: @Deepakyogi what is your URL? Does it contains `http://` or `https://`?

Comment: @DHAVALASODARIYA https://

Comment: @Deepakyogi Do you see my answer? I use `https://` to test. Does this could solve your problem?

Comment: @WendyZang i am tring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test the code you provided, and invoke on my own, it works well.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.webkit.WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);


        LaunchBrowserView("https://www.google.com");
    }
```

**Result:**
[image]

I have upload on GitHub, you could download from WebView folder for reference.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

**Updated:**

If you want to do this without axml file, you could create the layout in activity.

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        //SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout layout_main = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
        layout_main.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;

        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;

        layout_main.AddView(webView);
        SetContentView(layout_main);
        LaunchBrowserView("https://www.google.com", webView);
    }
    public void LaunchBrowserView(string authorizationServerUrl, WebView webView)
    {
        try
        {
            webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
            //web_view.Settings.= true;
            //web_view.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;
            webView.SetWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
            webView.Settings.LoadsImagesAutomatically = true;
            webView.LoadUrl(authorizationServerUrl);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

**Result:**

[image]

I have upload on GitHub, download from **WebViewDemo2** for reference.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

Comment: Hello @WendyZang in your solution you used  `var webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);` but i am not using  axml file any other way to declare webview

Comment: I have upadted the way without axml, you could download from github.

Comment: Hello @WendyZang i am not set `SetContentView(xml)` i am open Xaml page via this  `LoadApplication(new App());`

Comment: @Deepakyogi What is the xml? `LoadApplication(new App());` is used to call LoadApplication with an instance of the App class, it is not used to open xaml page.

Comment: Without use of SetContentView(layout_main) possible load url via WebView
in this way 
 `
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
webView.LoadUrl(authorizationServerUrl);
`

Comment: It is impossible. You need to load UI (layout view) first, and then run the code behind in activity.cs.

Comment: Any other way to load ulr

Comment: @Deepakyogi You want to load url in webview. I provide two ways. 1. Define in layout, and load url in activity. 2. Define all the controls via c# code, and load the url. What is the another way do you want?

Comment: Thanks for help me but now til i am stuck

Comment: What stuck you? You do this in Xamarin.Android via webview. In Xamarin.Android, you need a UI(layout view) and activity.cs. It is different with Xamarin.forms. You could make the answer to close the thread and post a new with another question.

Comment: i am using xamarin forms but i want to use native WebView

Comment: In Xamarin.forms, you could use `webview.Source`.